# missing slice of circle webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl

Im trying to draw a circle and instead of getting a full circle (360 deg), I get almost full circle and a missing 'slice'.
What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
//init:
            starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer);
            vertices = [1,0,1];
            for (j = 3; j < 360; j+=3) {        
                vertices[j] = starsList[i].factor * starsList[i].radius * Math.cos(j / 180.0 * Math.PI);
                vertices[j+1] = 0;
                vertices[j+2] = starsList[i].factor * starsList[i].radius * Math.sin(j / 180.0 * Math.PI);
            }

            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer.numItems = 120;

//draw
            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [x, y, z]);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            setMatrixUniforms();
            gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, starsList[i].circlePositionBuffer.numItems);
```

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

```
 vertices = [1,0,1];
```

should be:

```
vertices = [starsList[i].factor * starsList[i].radius,0,0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You never go back to 0° (or 360°), try replacing

```
for (j = 0; j < 360; j += 3)
```

by

```
for (j = 0; j <= 360; j += 3)
```

You can also move the

```
j / 180.0 * Math.PI
```

to

```
(j % 360) / 180.0 * Math.PI
```

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE please ? Will be easier to check what's wrong

Comment: Minimal complete and verifiable example

Comment: Did you also increase number of numItems?

Comment: But gl.LINE_LOOP should complete the circle. That sounds like a driver bug not implementing line loop correctly unless of course there is some other details missing.

Comment: Indeed I missed the GL_LINE_LOOP my bad on this one. But without a complete code example we won't be able to investigate further.

Comment: @PauliNieminen, any idea which part of the code is relevant?
I have some difficult to supply MCVE

Comment: also noticed that I get:

Comment: drawArrays: no VBO bound to enabled vertex attrib index 1!

Comment: any ideas why?
@Zouch

Comment: @arii What is the least lines html&js&GLSL which can draw the circle once to a canvas?     The missing VBO error sounds like you call gl.EnableVertexAttribArray twice in your setup code but rendering code only uses one vertex attribute slot (vertexPositionAttribute).

Comment: problem solved, it was my mistake.
vertices = [1,0,1] should be:
vertices = [starsList[i].factor * starsList[i].radius,0,0];

tnx for help and trying!